# if statement in php not respecting false case

Tags: php

PHP is still new to me so excuse me if I am missing something basic here.

I have some very simple code:

```
echo $_GET['initState'];

            if ($_GET['initState']) {
                $num = 10;
            }
            else {
                $num = PHP_INT_MAX;
            }

            echo $num;
```

And when I check my logs, I see the following: false10

So initState is false, and yet num is assigned to 10

But when I change the code to the following:

```
echo $_GET['initState'];

            if ($_GET['initState'] == 1) {
                $num = 10;
            }
            else {
                $num = PHP_INT_MAX;
            }

            echo $num;
```

My output is now working correctly: false9223372036854775807

What am I missing here?

Here is the @GET code:

```
@GET("getreleases.php")
    Call<ReleaseModelResponse> getReleases(@Query("initState") boolean initState);
```

Appreciate any insight that can be provided here.

**EDIT** Actually, maybe my code is not working correctly in either case, which is why I have been looking closely at this problem for a while now. I noticed my activity was always loading more than 10 items so this must mean neither versions of the code work correctly for me.

Just to be sure, I checked my logs again when performing an action that results in initState being true, and this is what I see: true9223372036854775807

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, what am I supposed to look at here? I have used empty and isset before and had no issues. But how do I apply this to my current problem?

Comment: Always first check `if (isset($_GET, 'initState]))` and only _then_ get the value out. Jumping straight to evaluating `$_GET['initState']` without an isset check is going to lead to hilarious bugs. In this case, you conclude that "So initState is false", but it isn't. All you currently know is that it _prints_ as `false`.

Comment: Remember too: `'false' !== false`. `$_GET` parameters are evaluated as strings, not booleans. And by being set to a non-empty value, your truthy check on a `'false'` string will evaluate to true.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans any tips on how to check isset prior to using any variable? Just the thought of this makes me think the code will get harder and harder to read with so many if statements

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['initState']);` to get the actual value of `$_GET['initState']`.

Comment: Having `isset` checks before using `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables does not make the code harder to read, in the same way adding any if statements before doing work reliant on the condition in them passing does not make code harder to read.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ah, is the practiceonly for GET, POST, etc. rather than all variables?

Comment: It's for any time you're trying to resolve a key on an associative array when you don't _know_ whether it actually exists or not (e.g I didn't just run code that explicitly created that key). First you check if the key is set, then you access it. That said, if you're using modern PHP, you can also use null coalescing operator `??`: e.g. `var $initState= $_GET['initState'] ?? false;`, which is another way to make sure that you're always working with consistent data. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version of your code, the if statement is checking if the value of `$_GET['initState']` is "truthy". In PHP, any non-empty string, non-zero number, or non-null value is considered "truthy". So even though the value of `$_GET['initState']` is "false", it is still considered "truthy" in the if statement; therefore $num is assigned the value of 10.

In the second version of your code, you are explicitly checking if the value of `$_GET['initState']` is equal to 1. Since it is not equal to 1, the else block is executed and `$num` is assigned the value of `PHP_INT_MAX`.

It seems that you are using this code in a REST API and sending a boolean value in the query parameter, but in PHP, booleans are not directly passed in query parameters, instead they are passed as strings "true" or "false", so in the first version of your code, the value of `$_GET['initState']` is "false" string and its considered truthy, but in the second version, the value of `$_GET['initState']` is "false" string and you are comparing it with 1, which is not equal and it's not truthy.

You could try to change the `if($_GET['initState'] == 1)` to `if($_GET['initState'] === "true")` or `if($_GET['initState'] == true)`, this will check for the boolean value and not the string.

Comment: Ah, not sure where but I had read somewhere that the boolean values were passed as either 1 or 0, which is why I ended up also trying it that way and thinking it was working finally lol.